# Trying to remove whitespaces and replace with a dash - C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
   char str[] = "hello this is a test";
   char str2[100];
   int i = 0;
   char *p = str;
   for (i; strlen(str); i++) {
    if (*p == ' ') {
        str2[i] = *p;
        p++;
    }
    else {
        str2[i] = '-';
        p++;
    }
   }
 printf("%s", &str2);
 _getch();
}
```

I am trying to replace blankspaces with dashes using pointers. I am not sure why this is not working for myself. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `strlen(str)` on its own isn't a useful condition in your `for` loop -- it's always true, because any non-zero value will evaluate to true. You want `i < strlen(str)` or better yet, `*p != '\0'`.

Comment: @MOehm Shouldn't `strlen` become 0 when `p` reaches the end of the string? Of course it should be `strlen(p)`.

Comment: @Osiris: Yes, that would be true if it were `strlen(p)`, but the code says `strlen(str)`. This code uses an unholy mix of indices and pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Your for condition is not correct.

   ```
   for (i; strlen(str); i++) {
   ```

The first item is the initiaizer and the second item is the condition. The condition should be `i<strlen(str)`

```
for (i=0; i< strlen(str); i++) {
```

2. The if condition is inverted. In the current case, you are replacing non space characters with space and space with `-`. Change it to.

   ```
   if (*p != ' ') {
   ```
3. `printf("%s", &str2);` printf with the `%s` takes address of the array, which is simply `str2`.  Change it to

   ```
   printf("%s", str2);
   ```

Comment: Thanks very much ! :D much appreicated

Answer (score 2):

Some problems:

- `for (i; strlen(str); i++)` should be `for (i; i<strlen(str); i++)`. Though preferably the `strlen` call should just be made once, before the loop.
- `if (*p == ' ')` should result in `str2[i] = '-';`, `else` ... `str2[i] = *p;`.
- `printf("%s", &str2);` should be `str2`.

Enable compiler warnings, then read & fix them when you encounter them.

Comment: Thank you Lundin :D

Answer (score 1):

`*p == ' '` is backwards, should be `*p != ' '`.

Further, to remove "whitepace" and not just a `' '`, use the standard library `isspace()` function.  from `<ctype.h>`. It expects a value in the `unsigned char` range or `EOF`.

```
//if (*p == ' ') {
//  str2[i] = *p;
if (isspace((unsigned char) *p) {
  str2[i] = '-';
```

---

> I am not sure why this is not working for myself.

The loop never ends.

`strlen(str)` in `for (i; strlen(str); i++)` only tests it the original string is not empty.  Not a useful loop test [@M Oehm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53189369/trying-to-remove-whitespaces-and-replace-with-a-dash-c#comment93267637_53189369).

Instead simply test if the *null character* is indexed.

```
// for (i; strlen(str); i++) {
for (i; str[i]; i++) {
// or 
for (i; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
// or 
for (i; *p; i++) {
// or 
for (i; *p != '\0'; i++) {
```

**Important**: After the loop, *null character* terminate `str2[]`.

```
str2[i] = '\0';
```

---

Along with some other improvements, a candidate solution:

```
int main() {
  const char str[] = "hello this is a test";
  char str2[sizeof str];

  size_t i = 0;
  do {
    str2[i] = isspace((unsigned char) str[i]) ? '-' : str[i];
  } while (str[i++]);

  printf("%s\n", str2);
  _getch();
}
```